# Acer Aspire 5742 - Black screen on boot

Tags: display, acer-aspire, laptop-display

Having trouble with an Acer Aspire 5742.  After pressing the power button the screen backlight comes on but it stays black.  The Windows(7) chime sounds and when plugged into an external VGA display everything shows fine.  I've checked all the ribbon connections and also just replaced the screen.  Have run Malware Bytes too.   Display is still not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a hardware issues. Malware Bytes isn't really going to do anything to diagnose or resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the laptop has a button usually on the F1 to F12 buttons.  It will say LCD or show a picture of external display.  Press the blue function or FN key with that button until the display show again.

Comment: Tried that with an external display plugged in - the key definitely works as the backlight on the laptop comes on and goes off as i press the key.  No windows though :(

Comment: @HoLiCow.  Go to Control Panel->Apperance and Personalization->Display->Screen Resolution.  On the Display dropdown check which display is selected as default.

Comment: If i set the laptop display to be default, the backlight comes on but the screen stays black

Comment: @HoLiCow If the laptop is still under warranty I would then suggest taking it in to a service provider that can check to see what the issue may be.